# SQL query to create new column without aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My table data

```
LOCATION GROUP  FUNCTION STATUS
L1         G1       F1   0
L1         G1       F1   1
L1         G1       F1   1
L1         G1       F2   1
L1         G1       F2   0
L1         G1       F2   0
L1         G1       F3   1
L1         G1       F3   0
L1         G1       F3   1
```

Output that I want

```
LOCATION GROUP F1   F2  F3
L1        G1   0    1   1
L1        G1   1    0   0
L1        G1   1    0   1
```

I try to use Select CASE but it don't work

Thanks you.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Can you explain the output resultset? It is not clear.

Comment: Marc B is right - breaking out single values into separate columns like this is why 'pivot' exists

Comment: Do you have another column that you can use to order the status values within each group?

Answer (score 0):

it is not giving exact result but we can go through like this

```
DECLARE @amount TABLE (LOCATION  VARCHAR(10),GROUPS VARCHAR(10),FUNCTIONS VARCHAR(10),Status INT)

INSERT INTo @amount (LOCATION,GROUPS,FUNCTIONS,Status)VALUES ('L1','G1','F1',0)
INSERT INTo @amount (LOCATION,GROUPS,FUNCTIONS,Status)VALUES ('L1','G1','F1',1)
INSERT INTo @amount (LOCATION,GROUPS,FUNCTIONS,Status)VALUES ('L1','G1','F1',1)
INSERT INTo @amount (LOCATION,GROUPS,FUNCTIONS,Status)VALUES ('L1','G1','F2',1)
INSERT INTo @amount (LOCATION,GROUPS,FUNCTIONS,Status)VALUES ('L1','G1','F2',0)
INSERT INTo @amount (LOCATION,GROUPS,FUNCTIONS,Status)VALUES ('L1','G1','F2',0)
INSERT INTo @amount (LOCATION,GROUPS,FUNCTIONS,Status)VALUES ('L1','G1','F3',0)
INSERT INTo @amount (LOCATION,GROUPS,FUNCTIONS,Status)VALUES ('L1','G1','F3',0)
INSERT INTo @amount (LOCATION,GROUPS,FUNCTIONS,Status)VALUES ('L1','G1','F3',1)

select LOCATION,GROUPS,Function1,Function2,Function3   from
(Select location,GROUPS,Status,FUNCTIONS from @amount) t
PIVOT (MAX(Status)FOR FUNCTIONS IN ([Function1],[Function2],[Function3]))AS p
```